# Using carriage return <cr> in a HL7 message

Tags: character-encoding, hl7, hl7-v2

The `carriage return` character (alias `<cr>`, `\r` or `\x0d`) is the designated segment terminator in a HL7 message.

Therefore this character is prohibited to be used in a field. However, some data may consist of line breaks. How is a line break encoded then? What is the way to go here? What's best practice?

There are some options I see:

1. Use line feed (`\n`) instead
2. Use this special escape sequence `\.br\`
3. Escape it like this `\x0d\`
4. Something different?

Which of these options are valid? What can I expect to see in a HL7 message? How should I encode line breaks in my own HL7 messages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In formatted text fields  **FT** your number 2 is the valid solution.

A different approach e.g. in reports or observation is to put every line in **TX** fields in a single segment and repeat the segments or to repeat the data fields with **~** .

In binary encapsulated data fields **ED** you have to use the relevant encoding e.g. **Hex** or **Base64**.

This does not exclude that you will see different ways may they be valid or not

Comment: From the version 2.3.1 HL7 standard: "..The escape character is whatever display ASCII character is specified in the Escape Character component of MSH-2-encoding characters..", you can read more in compressed form at http://www.hermetechnz.com/Documentation/sqlschema/index.html?hl7_escape_rules.htm